# How do I transfer real-time data in HTTP Streaming Protocol.

Tags: http, tcp, streaming, real-time, http-streaming

As I know, streaming is action that transfer of real-time data. And UDP is usually used for transfer of real-time data as RTP (Real-time transfer protocol). While HTTP Streaming used TCP, so how do it ensure real-time ?

Comment: Define what you mean by `real-time`, describe the data you want to transfer and in what way it is time-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

For streaming using input buffers on the client, imagine a flash video player (like youtube's one).. a part of the content is buffered first on the client and then begins to play; if the buffer runs out of information you have to stop to refill the buffer and resume playing.

You can use TCP for low bandwith consumption apps in real time, such as chats; but when you need a lot of bandwith it's not the best suited protocol, you should use UDP because it isn't connection oriented (for example VoD or Cable TV).

Hope this helps.

Comment: I disagree. Your distinction regarding bandwidth is inaccurate. Just because you want to transfer a lot of data, doesn't mean you pick UDP. It really depends on the application and it's requirements for and/or the consequences of latency, jitter, out-of-order reception and packet loss.

Comment: @MattH: So, can you show me some ways to ensure real-time in HTTP Streaming protocol. Because I must build a streaming video server in Windows Media Http Streaming protocol and i must solve this solution.

Comment: I agree with you matth, everything depends on the QoS you need. A chat is a real time app but does not influence jitter, a small latency. The question should define what he means with real time and what kind of streaming. What i intended to say is that if your application don't have to guarantee a QoS you can use TCP.

Comment: @Feida Kila : As i said, i want to streaming video in Windows Media Http Streaming Protocol.

Comment: you cannot stream video in real-time over tcp with a QoS. you need to use big buffers...so it's not real-time really.

Comment: you got the protocol, you have the technical stuff donde. read the manual -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc251059%28v=PROT.10%29.aspx . You'll have to attend the clients requests (load, play, pause, stop)

Comment: I'm buidling a streaming video server. As you said, solution is solved in client-side. How about server-side ?

Comment: I have read specification of protocol but i didn't see information about this.

Comment: the server should attend the client requests. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc251245%28v=PROT.10%29.aspx

Comment: Yes I know, but my problem is i don't know how to tranfer data to client to ensure real-time because this protocol using TCP.

Comment: please read the manual...the manual says  The Windows Media HTTP Streaming Protocol is used for transferring real-time multimedia data (that is, audio and video). It is a streaming protocol, which means that the protocol attempts to facilitate scenarios where the multimedia data is being transferred and rendered simultaneously (that is, video is being displayed and audio played).

Answer (score 0):

in the manual you got all the requests and responses, for example play

The following example shows a Play request.

```
GET /welcome HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
User-Agent: NSPlayer/12.0.7724.0
Host: SampleServer
X-Accept-Authentication: Negotiate, NTLM, Digest, Basic
Pragma: version11-enabled=1
Pragma: no-cache,rate=1.000,stream-time=0,stream-offset=4294967295:4294967295,packet-num=4294967295,max-duration=0
Pragma: xPlayStrm=1
Pragma: client-id=2338761264
Pragma: LinkBW=2147483647, AccelBW=2147483647, AccelDuration=18000, Speed=91268.055
Supported: com.microsoft.wm.srvppair, com.microsoft.wm.sswitch, com.microsoft.wm.startupprofile
Pragma: playlist-seek-id=64
Pragma: xClientGUID={BFE16E37-55EC-4AE4-A5A9-0B0D307F4B72}
Pragma: stream-switch-count=2
Pragma: stream-switch-entry=ffff:1:0 ffff:2:0 
Accept-Language: en-us, *;q=0.1
```

The following example shows a Play response.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/x-mms-framed
Server: Servername1/9.5.6001.18281
Date: Mon, 08 Mar 2010 18:39:44 GMT
Pragma: no-cache, client-id=2338761264, features="", timeout=60000, AccelBW=3500000, AccelDuration=18000, Speed=5.000
Cache-Control: no-cache, x-wms-content-size=51077, max-age=86399, user-public, must-revalidate, proxy-public, proxy-revalidate
Last-Modified: Tue, 22 Jan 2008 22:54:31 GMT
Etag: "51077"
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
X-StartupProfile: Rate=10,12,15,20,30;MaxBytes=459,459,459,459,459;Time=0,0,0,0,0;StartTime=3290;LastTime=15120;MaxDiffTime=0;MaxDiffSndTime=0;ByteRate=2538,2538,2538,2538,2538;
Supported: com.microsoft.wm.srvppair, com.microsoft.wm.sswitch, com.microsoft.wm.predstrm, com.microsoft.wm.fastcache, com.microsoft.wm.startupprofile
```

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc251235%28v=PROT.10%29.aspx][1]

[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc251235%28v=PROT.10%29.aspxenter code here`enter code here`

Comment: Yes. But in Play Request, after the response to client, I must transfer sequence data of a Video file to client. And i don't know how to transfer to ensure real-time.

Comment: use google, for example http://www.mediacollege.com/video/streaming/overview.html

Comment: To Create HTTP Streaming Video

   1. Create a video file in a common streaming media format
   2. Upload the file to your web server
   3. Make a simple hyperlink to the video file, or use special HTML tags to embed the video in a web page.

That's essentially all there is to it. When a user clicks the hyperlink, their media player opens and begins streaming the video file. If the file is embedded, it plays right there on the page.

Now let's look at how to create the necessary video files...

Comment: As i know TCP is reliable transmisson protocol. So. it usually is not used in real-time applications. And I want to know ways that http streaming protocols using to ensure real-time.

Comment: buffers as i explained you before

Comment: you could use the maximum packet size that TCP allows to reduce headers overhead

Comment: I think buffer and maximum packet size doesn't relate to real-time. I think it depend on speed of data transportation

Comment: one of the problems of TCP is headers overhead, increasing packet size you decrease headers overhead. you send fewer packets, you send fewer headers, so more bandwith for data